# How to disable swipe back to login screen in react native using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen, router

I want to disable the swipe left feature from the home screen to the login screen. Right now I tried using

```
gestureEnabled = {false}
panHandlers={null}
type={ActionConst.RESET} 
type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
drawerLockMode='locked-closed' gesturesEnabled={false}
```

This is my Router class

```
 <Router>
            <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                <Scene key="auth" >
                    <Scene key="login" component={LoginXScr} hideNavBar={true} initial/>
                    <Scene key="forgotPassword" component={FGPassword} hideNavBar={true}/>
                    
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="main"  >
                    <Scene key="homescr" component={Home} hideNavBar={true} initial/>
                    <Scene key="explorecr"  direction="vertical" component={Explore} hideNavBar={true} />
                    
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="loading">
                    <Scene key="loaderloading" component={LoadingXScr} hideNavBar={true} />
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="paymentconf">
                     <Scene key="confirmationscr" direction="vertical"  component={ConfrmPage} hideNavBar={true} />
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="setuprec">
                    <Scene key="setuprescr" direction="vertical"  component={RecurringConfPage} hideNavBar={true} />
                </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
```

None of them are working for me. Can anyone guide me what should be the correct way to disable the left swipe so that the screen does not swipe back to the login screen. I need to implement both in iOS and Android the same.

Comment: Any help on this

Comment: Its been more than a week... no reply.. has no one faced this issue. If not then any knowledge what we can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Drawer
                type="reset"
                key="drawer"
                contentComponent={DrawerComponent}
                drawerWidth={250}
                drawerPosition='left'
                hideNavBar={true}
              >
```

Comment: just add the type reset prop to the scene you wish to not be able to swipe backward, this is with react native router flux